# How can I parse file-paths in gerrit-code-review site?

Tags: gerrit

I want to parse file paths in gerrit-code-review with json api.
For example, in https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/10007, I want to get file paths.
I tried to json api in java, but i couldn't view file path.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this information using the Gerrit REST API.

See more info [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api.html).